# Online or offline function PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a "community". And of course I would like to be able to tell if a user is online or offline.

I've created so that when you log in a row in my table UPDATE's to 1 (default is 0) and then they're online. And when they log out they're offline. But if they don't press the Log out button, they will be online until they press that button.

So what I would like to create is:

- After 5 minutes of inactivity the row in my database should UPDATE to 0.

What I'm looking for is how to do this the easiest way. Should I make an mysql_query which UPDATE's the row to 1 every time a page is loaded. Or is there another way to do it?

Comment: You also have to account for someone staying on the same page for more than 5 minutes. I'd suggest setting up an Ajax request that pings your server every few minutes.

Comment: @SimpleCoder I've never worked with Ajax before. So I don't know how to do this. But I get what you're saying. It's not fair that someone on same page for 5 minutes is turned to offline ;)

Comment: It's better to keep record of the user's activity, for example by updating/inserting a record in the table, and specifying an interval (let's say 15 minutes) for which a user is to be considered online. When you want to check wether or not the user is online just check his last activity record and see if it was 15 <interval> minutes or less ago, or not.

Comment: @Kolind: using jQuery its very easy to do ajax, just do `jQuery.ajax('/useralivepage.php?name=abc')` and the page will get called. populate the name in php.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of using a boolean "Online" field, use a DateTime. When a user makes a request to the page, update the DateTime to NOW(). When you are gathering your list of current users online, your WHERE clause would be something like `WHERE lastSeen > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 Minutes)`

Update: To retrieve individual online status.

`select if(lastSeen > date_sub(now(), interval 15 minutes), 1, 0) as status from table where userid=$userid`

Comment: And what if the user went to get some coffee and returns 20 minutes later? he'll be disconnected?

Comment: No. He'll just appear as offline and then as online

Comment: This was what I'm looking for. Then would I have to have a mysql_query() on EVERY single page to do this?

Comment: He'll be shown as offline, because it's beyond the 5 minute inactivity threshold the OP has set.

Comment: @Riduko OP's request:`After 5 minutes of inactivity the row in my database should UPDATE to 0.` So that's the correct behaviour.

Comment: @kolind Yes, you will need to do `update onlineTable set lastSeen = now() where userid=$userid` on each page request. Put this query in a header or include file.

Comment: Optimization note: if you make a separate table for online/offline data, make it a MEMORY table

Comment: @AndrewR Hi again. Hope you're looking. I'm using this method. But now I need to create so that if a user is online there should be a green picture if not a red one. (I have the pictures ofc). How would you do this? Before I just had: if($row['status']==0) use the red picture if not the green one. But I can't do that now.

Comment: It wouldn't let me add the query in the comments.. Weird. I updated the original answer with the query to pull just the status of one user.

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial is quite handy: [Who Is Online Widget With PHP, MySQL & jQuery](http://tutorialzine.com/2010/03/who-is-online-widget-php-mysql-jquery/)

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you don't want to set up a cron job, that would execute some code every 5 minutes, you have no options. But, actually, I think the following approach would be much more efficient:

1. Change your 1/0 column to `timestamp`
2. On each user request update that `timestamp` to current DateTime.
3. When checking for active users, check if that `timestamp` is less than 5 minutes from `now`

This way you'll be having actual data on users and no recurring queries - just one additional update per request

Answer (score 0):

If you will update the row only on page load, then some of information would be incorrect.
Let's assume that user have opened page and is writing really long text or something. He is doing it for half an hour now. And your database ny now is already updated and he is counted as offline user.

I would write javascript that pings you back each 5 minutes, if opened tab is active.
This ping updates database field 'last_activity' to NOW(). And to count online users, or check if user is online you'll need to compare 'last_activity' to NOW() minus five minutes.

Comment: The javascript would have to know if the user is actively interacting with the page. Otherwise, if you just have javascript that pings back to the server every 5 minutes, a page open in the browser would continue to show you online.

Answer (score 0):

Simpliest ways (IMHO):

- You can count sessions in session_save_path() dir.
- you can store last visit timestamp in DB, and count rows with (timestamp > current_timestamp - somedelay).